# Taxonomy Term View not showing image field

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Drupal 7, Views 3

I have created a Taxonomy Term View for a particular vocabulary. If I set the Format Show option to "Fields", and add the Taxonomy name and image fields, then for some reason only the name shows. If I change it to "Rendered entity" then everything works fine. Another weirdness: this is only for some vocabularies - for some other vocabularies, the fields option works just fine (it shows the image). Any thoughts on why this might be? Any ideas how to debug this? Thanks guys.

Comment: Do all the vocabularies share the same image field?

Comment: Hmmm apparently not - the vocabs that work all use a field called "field_image", and the ones that don't use "field_brand_image"

Comment: I'm an idiot - I was selecting the wrong field in my View. There were 3, and I just chose the top 1, because I saw the second one just said "alias of ..." and assumed they were all just aliases of each other. They were not. The third one was the right one. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, well, as said in the comment, be sure to either have the same field or add all image fields :)

Answer (score 0):

A detailed doc on exposing term images is available here https://drupal.org/node/1224916